# Add another button to close the Bootstrap Simple Sidebar

Tags: javascript

I'm using https://codepen.io/Philippe_Fercha/pen/yawbqB to add a sidebar to my site. I want to add another button to the sidebar to close my menu in mobile mode.
But by adding the code below, this feature fails.

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
```

How do I create another button to close this menu?

Comment: There is already an element with `id="menu-toggle"`, you cannot paste the same id to another element. Please refer to this fork of your fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydpadp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second button needs unique id. For example: `id="menu-toggle2"`.
After that you have to register click method for this button as well:

```
$("#menu-toggle2").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Alternatively you can use this method (posted by @GrafiCode Studio) to register click for all links having specific attribute:
`$('a[href="#menu-toggle"]')`